# if crpt_img.shape == original_img.shape and not(np.bitwise_xor(crpt_img,original_img).any()):

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

```
if crpt_img.shape == original_img.shape and not(np.bitwise_xor(crpt_img,original_img).any()):

ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U15') dtype('<U15') dtype('<U15')
```

I am doing `bitwise_xor` operation on two images. and getting this error. Please help.

Comment: The error message (trying to add numpy arrays that contain 15 character long strings) doesn't seem to relate to the code you pasted. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the full traceback of the error message to allow reproducibility of your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please apply a title that summarizes the problem instead of code as explained in [ask].